# Shellexecute undefined error

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-8.1

just for a little background on myself.  I used to code couple years ago.  Last year, I started coding in java for Android apps.  Now, I am trying to make metro apps for windows 8.1.  I am trying to get my app to open the browser when a button is clicked.  I am using shellexecute to do that, but I keep getting an error.

```
void App3::MainPage::hi(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{

    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://yourwebpage.com",
        NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

}
```

The error that I am getting is :    1   IntelliSense: identifier "ShellExecute" is undefined

Sorry If it is a stupid question.

Comment: "ItelliSense" errors are just hints for you during programming, what is the actual error from the compiler? (although it does hint to you either missing an include or not using the right arguments)

Answer (score 1):

`ShellExecute` is not available for "Metro" apps (Store apps). If you look at the [API page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx), near the bottom it says **Requirements:** Windows XP **[Desktop apps only]**

In order to launch the browser from your app, use [`Windows::System::Launcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It worked flawlessly when I implemented it into a onclick event.  But, when I tried to get it to open the website when the app opens it fails.  What I did is I made a load event for the button and inserted the code.